# Replace std::cout with a define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, cout

I try to force my compiler to replace any `std::cout` occurrence in my code with something.
But when I write something like that:

`#define std::cout (*some code*)`

My compiler spit on my face. Is there a way to do this ?

EDIT :

Here is the code snippet:

`# define std::cout (std_out << std::cout)`

(std_out is a file I've previously open)

and the error on a line with a std::out occurence

> the global scope has no "cout"

Comment: To do what? You haven't told us what it is you tried to replace it with or what error you got...

Comment: Maybe a search-replace would be a better idea here. Replace every occurrence of `std::cout` with something else that can be easily modified to call `std::cout` when you need to revert the changes.

Comment: Also tell us what it spat?

Comment: I suspect colon symbol can't be used as identifier.

Comment: To redirect things, better use `std::cout.rdbuf(...)`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse To redirect, you just don't use `std::cout`.  Except in small experiments, you really shouldn't have an `std::cout <<` in your code to begin with.

Comment: In case of doubt why a macro doesn't work, try calling your compiler with the `-E` flag. It would tell you that with your `#define std::cout (std_out << std::cout)` from the question `std::cout << 42;` becomes `::cout (std_out << std::cout)::cout << 42;` This isn't what you wanted, is it?

Answer (score 6):

You define an identifier, not an arbitrary expression.  `std` is
an identifier; your define will cause the compiler to replace
every instance of the identifier `std` with `::cout (*some
code*)`.  So it's not surprising that the compiler doesn't like
it: `std::cout << toto` becomes `::cout (*some code*)::cout <<
toto` and `std::vector` becomes `::cout (*some code*)::vector`.

If you'd explain what you're actually trying to achieve, we could probably help you better.

Comment: Thanks, it's more clear now. EDIT: I try to redicrect all my output in a file both in my console.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to force my compiler to replace any std::cout occurence in my code with something

That's a **bad idea**. If you are looking for configurable behavior on your output stream, replace all occurrences of `std::cout` in your code with `out`, and declare `out` as `std::ostream& out` (= whatever stream type you may need).

> My compiler spit on my face. Is there a way to do this ?

Not as such. No. You could write:

```
#define OUTPUT std::cout

OUTPUT << "a = " << a << std::endl;
```

but you needing a #define to disable (or redirect) your output stream is a sign of bad design (i.e. your define is not the problem you should be trying to solve).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own version of cout, that actually calls cout, you can place any custom code there:

```
std::ostream& my_cout() {
   /// ...
   return std::cout << "a custom message";
}

int main() {
   my_cout() << " hi" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I can't use that, i'm forced to call std::cout.

Comment: Not really, i just want know how to do that.

Comment: Although I do not get the idea behind how you want to do it exactly.  I would suggest `.rdbuf` method as @MarcGlisse suggested.

Comment: I want to, when i write `std::cout << "Bla"`, "Bla" is print in the output console both a file (output.log by exemple).

Comment: @PanzerKadaver yes, then go for `rdbuf`.